# Wordpress - Display what categories post is in?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get what categories the post is displayed on the individual post page.

It is currently showing all the categories used across the site.

I've had a look on the WordPress Codex but can't find what I'm looking for.

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Please add more detail. are you wanting to do somthing in the post body or show only that category in the sidebar? And what have you tried?

Comment: I want to display a list of the categories along the bottom of the individual post. Only the ones that are selected for that specific post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [the_category() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) inside the_loop